# Unable to create new flutter project in Android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, project

[image]I recently updated my Android studio to Android Studio Iguana|2023.2.1 Canary 11 and since then, the option to create new flutter project is not showing again.
I have actually tried all the options from other peoples here on stack overflow but it's still not showing. Both flutter plugin and dart plugin has been installed as well as enabling android sdk and NDK support and yet no change. I have uninstalled and reinstalled all these things several times as well as restarting my android studio but nothing is still working. I really need help on how to resolve it as it's becoming so frustrating.
Here is the windows appearance when I tried to create a new project

Comment: I'm having same issue, it's captured by this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6890

Comment: Have you been able to solve it @ctwheels?if yes please tell me how to resolve it

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution other than using older version of Android Studio